# Connection error with camera in machine learning

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a project use python and Techable machine website with Raspberry pi to build a machine,which will identify the error product in my factory,but when i want to run the system,it said that: my camera is not plugged in or wrong.

So has anyone met that case or any idea to help me fix it ??

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer as is, [please include some details on your setup and code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)